# Passing a variable from view to HTML

Tags: python, django, django-templates, django-views

Assuming in views.py I have the variable:

```
a = 5
```

And I want to include this information in my HTML page where I can do something like:

```
 {%if a = 5%}
 Do something.
 {%endif%}
```

I was wondering what I have to pass into render_to_response in order to get the value a, or is it not at all possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add items to a context dictionary that will then become available within the template. [See the docs.](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/shortcuts/#render-to-response)

```
def some_view(request):
    context = {
        'a': 5
    }

    return render_to_response(
        'my_template.html',
        context,
        context_instance=RequestContext(request)
    )
```